# Are large panels always created by glueing smaller panels together?

Tags: panel

I have seen some youtube videos on the topic of woodworking. I have noticed two approaches for side panels.

The first approach involves using timber to create a frame for the side and then cutting grooves into the wood. Then an engineered wood panel (usually plywood) goes into the center. There is little work involved.

The second approach is to take several planks of wood. First cut their left and right side using table saw to make the edges be completely flat and straight. Then use wood glue to stick the panels together along their width to create a single large panel of wood. Now this large panel that is made of smaller glued wooden panels is put through planer and sanded to make it flat and then used in the design.

The end result gives two different aesthetics. Now my questions are:

1. How is choice made between these two methods?
2. When we use the second approach, won't the expansion and contraction of wood cause the glued panels to fall apart?

Comment: Have a think about how common glueing up panels from individual boards is..... do you want to rethink asking no. 2?

Comment: BTW the first approach you describe is called 'floating panel construction' and the basic idea predates commercial plywood by over 100 years. Even today it's quite common to use solid wood for the panel instead of ply or MDF (this is incidentally another example of where, and why, grain would be oriented vertically — to minimise problems from expansion and contraction).

Comment: You don't _have_ to use a table saw for jointing boards.  I've used a jointer plane (aka try plane) in the past (but this was in the mid 70's, at school).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are large panels always created by glueing smaller panels together?

**No.** Plywood and MDF are often used when that makes sense. Glass or acrylic are obviously used, and I realize that you probably didn't have see-through doors in mind for this question, but other than the material there's not much difference between that and wood panels. (Also: in the future it might not be unusual to use [transparent wood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparent_wood_composite) panels. Other materials might be called for if the panel needs to be lightweight, fire resistant, bulletproof, etc.

> How is choice made between these two methods?

It's made by considering various factors such as:

- **aesthetics:** Plywood can work well for flat panels, but not for raised panels. MDF can be used for flat or raised panels, but it's not very attractive so it usually makes sense only for projects that will be painted. Solid wood is good for flat or raised panels and can be very attractive, but since wide boards are very expensive, solid panels tend to be glued up from narrower boards. Panels can also be covered with veneer to get a single-piece look at a lower cost.
- **cost:** Probably everybody is concerned with keeping costs down, but it may be a higher priority if you're mass producing a product than it is if you're a weekend warrior or custom furniture maker building just one or two copies of a project.
- **labor:** Gluing boards up into panels, and then flattening them, involves a lot more work than just cutting sheet stock to length and width.
- **capabilities:** Depending on your tools, workspace, availability of materials, and so on, some options may be off the table.
- **quality/durability:** Many people consider solid wood to be higher quality, more durable, more likely to become an heirloom, and so on.

> When we use the second approach, won't the expansion and contraction of wood cause the glued panels to fall apart?

Not if you build it right. The boards that make up a panel expand mainly across their width, but the glue joints normally run lengthwise, so those joints aren't subject to much expansion. And the main idea behind frame-and-panel construction is to allow for seasonal movement.

The panel should be captured in the groove on the inside of the frame, so it's held securely without glue while remaining free to expand or contract seasonally. The stiles and rails of the frame are narrow enough that there's little expansion across their width, and the grain runs along their long dimensions so the frame stays the same size even though the panel it contains changes.

Panels made from stable materials like plywood and MDF are sometimes glued into their frames for extra strength. Solid wood panels should never be glued in; they're said to "float" in the groove in the frame, which is deep enough to accept the expected seasonal expansion.

Comment: If I need to make a 1.5m by 0.75m desk, do I search for a wood of that size? or taken smaller panels and join them with glue to make a panel of this size?

Comment: @quantum231 Do you want your desk to be solid wood, or are you OK with plywood? If you want a solid wood desk top, you'll probably need to glue boards up to make the top. It's not impossible to find a single slab of wood that large, but they're usually quite expensive and probably thicker than you'd want for a desk. If you're OK with plywood, you just buy a sheet (normally 4'x8' in the US) and cut it to the size you want. The store may also be willing to cut it for you, but you'll usually still have to buy the whole sheet.

Comment: ok, now since timber is expensive, what about using Plywood top with a thin sheet (or multiple plank sheets) of timber on the top so the top looks like real timber? This could be 2mm thick.

Comment: @quantum231 Plywood is made by laminating thin sheets of wood together, so the top will look like "real timber" because it is. And you can get plywood with surface veneers in many different species, so if you want it to look like oak, maple, cherry, etc.,  you can do that. You'd only be able to see that the top is plywood at the edges. There are various ways to hide the edges, but we're drifting a bit off topic.

Comment: So Plywood has different types as well?

Comment: @quantum231 Sure, there are many, many types of plywood. The face veneers can be from various species, the number and species of the interior veneers, whether there are voids or not, quality of the face veneers, surface may be pre-stained and/or pre-finished, etc are all variable.

Comment: A 1.5m x 0.75m single piece of wood for your desktop, @quantum231, would A) be beautiful, B) be exceedingly rare and C) be eye-bleedingly expensive (because B)!

Comment: @FreeMan Right -- you'd probably need to buy a thicker slab and then have someone resaw it, but slabs cost hundreds to thousands of dollars. Also, a single piece that size is going to be prone to cracking or warping at normal desktop thickness of 3/4"-1".

Comment: By the way, since we can get engineered wood that has a thin layer of natural wood on top, why even bother with using real timber for making furniture? Also, when it comes to making furniture that shall be painted white or some other colour, I guess timber is not even required. Is this correct?

Comment: @quantum231 There are plenty of reasons to use solid wood, and also good reasons to use alternatives like plywood. For example, it's easy to cut curves in solid wood, and you don't have to worry about hiding edges, but plywood is very strong in both directions and quite stable. Design is all about understanding the materials and tradeoffs, and making the best choice for your needs. There's plenty of furniture made from engineered products.